# When are variables a part of a closure?

Tags: c#

Say I wanted to make an anonymous getter function that would return the current value of a member variable foo. I might write:

```
Func<int> myFunction = delegate() { return foo; };
```

But say I wanted a function that takes the value of foo, binds that value into its closure, and then returns that value every time it's called. I'd write the same thing:

```
Func<int> myFunction = delegate() { return foo; };
```

How does the C# compiler tell the difference? Is there any way to be more specific in asking what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous functions *always* use closures.

There is no way to capture a variable's value only.

If you don't want the function to see changes to the variable, you can make a separate temporary variable and use that in the function,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Eric Lippert's two-part article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) about this, and specifically modified closure "bugs". He does a better job explaining this than anyone else I've read.

@SLaks is right though about being unable to capture the variable's *value*.

Answer (score 0):

"Anonymous functions always use closures" or they close over whatever variables they are referencing.  It's possible to properly scope these referenced variables with a factory method so that you're `Func<int>` returns the value of `foo` at the time the `Func<int>` is created.  Take the following.

```
private static Func<int> CreateFooFunc(int scopedFoo)
{
    return () => scopedFoo;
    //FYI, the line above is more concise version of line below
    //return () => { return scopedFoo; };
    //which is a more concise version of line below
    //return delegate() { return scopedFoo; };
}
```

or non-statically, depending on use case.

```
private Func<int> CreateFooFunc()
{
    var scopedFoo = foo;
    return () => scopedFoo;
}
```

or better non-static version IMHO (others may disagree)

```
private Func<int> CreateFooFunc()
{
    return CreateFooFunc(foo)
}
```

You can now do the following and myFunction will contain a function which when evaluated, will return the value of `foo` at the time it was created.

```
Func<int> myFunction = CreateFooFunc(foo);
```

Keep in mind that if the value of `foo` itself was mutable (a POCO for instance) then you would have to copy it or something inside of `CreateFooFunc` in order to have the same effect.